# Model Theory: Group Substructures

Tags: group-theory, model-theory, universal-algebra

Maria Manzano defines a group in two different ways:

1. $\langle A, e, + \rangle$ in which $e$ is the neutral element, $+$ is associative, and each element has an inverse.
2. $\langle A, e, \space^{-1}, + \rangle$ in which $e$ is the neutral element, $+$ is associative, and for each $x\in A$, $x+x^{-1}=e$.

The question is this: Is any substructure of a group, a group? I think if you consider the first definition, the answer could be no, but if you consider the second it would be yes, but the author says the second definition is an alternative to the first. Am I wrong?

Comment: Neither of these definitions are correct! You meant to say $+$ is *associative*, not commutative.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Thanks. Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right : in the first definition, you may have substructures that are not themselves groups. An example is $(\mathbb N,+,0)$ sitting in $(\mathbb Z,+,0)$ : it is clearly a substructure but not a group.

The two definitions are equivalent in a looser sense : the *structures* are the same, but the notion of substructure will not be the same.

I don't know which book you're reading from, but if it's about group theory, it won't matter because people will always say "subgroup" rather than substructure. The difference comes into play if you're reading something about model theory or universal algebra.

Comment: Thanks. I'm reading _Model Theory_ by Maria Manzano.

Comment: By the way, I don't think there's a general notion of substructure in the vast framework of model theory. There's one in universal algebra (which encompasses both given examples), and more generally for any relational structure in which every relation can be (and is explicitly) viewed as a partial map (e.g., a field). For instance it's certainly not clear what a substructure is in a poset.

Comment: @YCor : I don't know how standard it is, but in my model theory classes and in the books I read, "substructure" was defined as "subset which is stable under the functions; together with the induced functions and the induced relations". Of course it's more relevant if you only have functions or only relations, but I remember it being defined in general.

Comment: You replied too quickly, I was about to erase my comment for this reason :) I tend to think of functions as relations, which doesn't affect types, definable subsets, elementary equivalence etc., but obviously affects what is meant by substructure.

Answer (score 0):

Given a $\langle A,e,+\rangle$ as described, the inverse that is guaranteed to exist is necessarily unique. That is, 
If $x+y=e$ and also $x+z=e$, then 
$$\tag1y=y+e=y+(x+z)=(y+x)+z=e+z=z.$$
Hence we can defin a map ${}^{-1}\colon A\to A$ that sends each $x\in A$ to its uniquely determined inverse. This allows us to extend $\langle A,e,+\rangle$ in a unique way to $\langle A,e,{}^{-1},+\rangle$, i.e., the second kind of structure turns out to be equivalent to the first kind.

If we could not use $(1)$, your doubts would be valid.